# How to Implement Recommendation system with Weka

Tags: java, spring-mvc, analytics, weka, recommendation-engine

I am making a Shopping Cart, it's a fairly small website. I am using Spring Framework with MySQL back-end. I want to implement a recommendation system using Weka. I just want to know how this will work?
How the recommendations will actually be served to the site visitors?
Will Weka work from inside my Web App, by keeping Weka JARs in Classpath?

I need an overview of such implementation, I will look into the details myself. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many ways of doing this, but one would be to create features for each item in your store. The features could as an example be genre, grading or author if you sell books. Next, cluster the instances in your dataset based on the feature using some clustering method, e.g. EM, that is available under the unsupervised methods in Weka.

After that you will have a number of clusters that contains instances that are more similar to eachother, than to instances outside the cluster (with regards to the features available). Then, if a person has bought book A you check in which cluster that book is and recommend another item from that cluster.

Note: this is a very trivial solution.

Comment: Thanks Martin, It might be trivial but at least now I know how to start! I will ask further questions if I'll get stuck. Thank you.